# Materialize datepicker not triggering ui

Tags: javascript, node.js, datepicker, pug, materialize

I'm doing a form using Jade Template and Materialize. I've been using Materialize forms elements as Select and File Input Button without a problem, but, not Date Picker.

The Date Picker element is initialized, but, when I the input is clicked nothing happens.

My folders structure:

```
.
|-- bower_components
|   |-- jquery
|   `-- Materialize
|-- public
|   |-- javascripts
|   |   `-- form.js
|-- views
|   |-- devices
|   |   |-- create.jade
|   |   `-- index.jade
|   |-- mixins
|   |   |-- form.jade
|   |   |-- form
|   |   |   `-- materialize.jade
|   `-- layout.jade
```

The route goes to `create.jade`, which calls `layout.jade` and `form.jade`. Inside `layout.jade` are called `jquery.js`, `materialize.js` and `materialize.min.css` before the `<body>` and is created a **block footer-script**.

The `create.jade` outputs the following HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <form method="post" action="/devices/inserir" class="col s12" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="row">
        <h4 class="col s12">Device</h4>
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="validate"/>
          <label for="title">Title</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <select multiple="multiple" name="platform" id="platform">
            <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Choose a platform</option>
            <option value="PS4">Playstation 4</option>
            <option value="PC">PC</option>
          </select>
          <label for="platform">Platform</label>
        </div>

        <!-- materialize select -->
        <div class="col s12">
          <label for="birthdate">Birthdate</label>
          <input type="date" id="birthdate" class="datepicker">
        </div>


        <div class="file-field input-field col s12">
          <div class="btn">
            <span>File</span>
            <input type="file"/>
          </div>
          <div class="file-path-wrapper">
            <input type="text" name="image" class="file-path validate"/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col s12">
          <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- added in block footer-script -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/form.js"></script>
```

The `form.js` file is responsable for initialize my `select` and `date picker` fields. Here it's code:

**form.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.datepicker').pickadate({
      selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
      selectYears: 15 // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
    });
    $('select').material_select();
  });
});
```

And as my printscreen shows, my `form.js` is called without a problem, since my `select` works just fine:

[image: Materialize form]

I just want to know why there is no action happening when I click the datepicker element, and how can I solve this.

For reference: [Materialize forms: Date Picker](http://materializecss.com/forms.html#date-picker)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem changing the jQuery file.

The jQuery version used in my system was **jQuery v2.2.1** and the version advised to use at Materialize to date is **jQuery v2.1.1**.

Minor changes in versions shouldn't make something stop working, but, this is the case right now.